# How to consume SL/RIA as WCF

Tags: wcf-ria-services

Using VS2012 and beginning with a SL Business Application project, I added 
an EF model Model1, removed the tt files, changed code gen to Default and built the project. Then I added DomainService1 with various tables. OData was not selected.

Starting the app it appears there is a service available:

[image]

But if we click the url, we expect to see XML, and it doesn't work. Appending ?wsdl should cause XML to be sent to the browser, but I just get the illustrated page. Trying it with svcutil as suggested by this page produces this:

```
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool [Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication 
Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.17929] Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  
All rights reserved.

Attempting to download metadata from 'http://localhost:57880/Ria1-Web-DomainService1.sv
c?wsdl' using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO. Generating files...     
Warning: No code was generated. If you were trying to generate a client, this could be 
because the metadata documents did not contain any valid contracts or services or 
because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assemblies. 
Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the tool.

Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas make sure to use
the /dataContractOnly option.
```

This appears to suggest the MEX endpoint isn't properly designed, so out came my WCF books, but there is no correlation between what they think ought to be in `<system.serviceModel>` and what actually *was* there:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment 
      aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

What do I need to add to the config to expose the metadata?

Answer (score 0):

While preparing this question it occurred to me to wonder what happens to the config when you *do* specify OData. This turned out to be the right question. You get this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment 
      aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <domainServices>
      <endpoints>
        <add name="OData" 
          type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.ODataEndpointFactory, 
                System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.OData, 
                Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </endpoints>
    </domainServices>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

This gave me a few more search terms. Combining information from various sources led to this:

```
<add name="Soap" 
     type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.SoapXmlEndpointFactory, 
     Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, 
     Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

which totally failed to work until I added a reference to this:

[image: Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.EndPoints]

Whereupon everything lit up and there was much rejoicing.